# Russian keyboard doesn't work

Tags: keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu Bionic Beaver and I added the Russian phonetic keyboard, but when I switch the keyboard to 'ru' in the top right corner, it doesn't work and I still type English letters. How can I fix this?